# How to set java classpath programatically for different directory at runtime?

Tags: java, class, runtime, classpath, classloader

Write two classes (say "A" and "B") , in class "A" create an instance of class "B". Compile class "A" in some directory "D1" and class "B" in "D2" , now A.class and B.class are in two separate directories. Try to run class "A" from directory "D1" (it will say class "B" not found). If you set classpath to both directories then it will work (try it out!)
Try to set the classpath from the class "A" itself (instead of specifying the classpath in the DOS shell , try to set in in your java prog!).

Class A is in Directory 1;

```
public class A{
    A(){
        System.out.println("class A is called");
    }
    public static  void main(String args[]){
        System.setProperty("java.class.path", "D:/task2/Dir2");
        B obj = new B();
        
    }
}
```

Class B is in Directory 2

```
public class B{
    B(){
           System.out.println("class B is called");
    }
    public static  void main(String args[]){
        
        
    }
}
```

`System.setProperty("java.class.path", "D:/task2/Dir2");`

the above one doesn't work .
Should i need to create my own classloader or any other way we have?

Comment: I think it's about time to looking into [Java packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html). Using what's available in Java by default is going to be a lot easier than writing your own class loader.

Comment: Yes, to complete this exercise, you'll need your own ClassLoader implementation.  But honestly, nobody does this kind of thing.  There are better ways of solving this problem.